# Enviar token Jwt desde php

Tags: php, jwt

Estoy desarrollando una integración de OpenId desde php y tengo que enviar un token jwt a un endpoint.

Utilizo Jwt firebase para generar y validar los jwt:

```
$key = 'xxxx';

$data = array(
    "tenantId" => self::TENANT_ID,
    "clientId" => self::CLIENT_ID,
    "objectId" => $oid,
    "iss" => "issuer",
    "aud" => "audience",
    "exp" => 1474980478,
    "nbf" => 1474976878,
    "state" => $state,
    "message" => $msg,
    "notifierAppID" => self::B2C_ID
);

$jwt = JWT::encode(
    $data,
    $key,
    'HS256'
);
```

La estructura del Endpoint es algo como:

```
https://dominio/{prametro}/app/{parametro}/estado
```

La idea es que que tengo que enviarle el token que genero para uqe me devuelva datos sobre un objeto.

Una vez generado el jwt, ¿Como puedo enviar el jwt al endpoint desde PHP?

Estoy intentando con este código, pero no parece funcionar:

```
    // Create a stream
    $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>
                "Authorization: bearer ".$jwt
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    // Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
    $result = file_get_contents($endpoint, false, $context);
```

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar tu código por favor?

Comment: He actualizado un poco la pregunta, la verdad es que estoy un poco perdido con el Jwt, es mi primer desarrollo utilizandolo.

Comment: Ya se ve mejor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has probado a enviar la petición por curl?

```
$crl = curl_init();

$header = array();
$header[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$header[] = 'Authorization: bearer '.$jwt;

curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$rest = curl_exec($crl);

curl_close($crl);

print_r($rest);
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, gracias.